# Clipboard automatically clears upon C# program exit

Tags: c#, clipboard

I want the contents of the Clipboard in a C# program to be retained when the program is exited.

For example in a simple Winform application with the following button click event:

```
  private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
     string preResultText = Clipboard.GetData( DataFormats.StringFormat ) as string;

     DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
     dataObject.SetData( DataFormats.StringFormat, true, "test" );
     Clipboard.SetDataObject( dataObject );

     string resultText = Clipboard.GetData( DataFormats.StringFormat ) as string;

  }
```

preResultText should be the same as resultText when the program is ran twice and the button is pushed once during each run.

Instead, I get:

preResultText = null

resultText = "test"

The boolean parameter in SetData is presumably meant to solve this problem, but doesn't on my machine. I have read elsewhere that this is not default behavior, but that still leaves me wondering why it happens. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set the `copy` parameter to `true` on the call of `SetDataObject`:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, true);
```

In your case, you could possibly better use `GetText` and `SetText`:

```
string preResultText = Clipboard.GetText();

Clipboard.SetText("test");

string resultText = Clipboard.GetText();
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I needed to pass true as a parameter *somewhere* and this was it.